# CNN autoplay video has changed and must be blocked another way?

Tags: video-streaming

In recent days, the way that CNN autoplays its videos has changed and old methods of blocking them no longer work. I suspect it has something to do with their using HTML5 instead of Flash. Any suggestion on how to block them now?

Answer (score 2):

After further searching, I've found plug-ins for both Firefox and Chrome that handle both the Flash and HTML5 attempts to auto-play videos on CNN. It appears that CNN is now trying up to six times to auto-play a video, and these plug-ins catch them all! https://www.technologyhint.com/stop-video-autoplay-chrome-firefox/

Comment: I have Chrome 58, and installed both of those extensions.  CNN videos still autoplay about 75% of the time.

Comment: None of these work in Chrome anymore (Chrome 62).

Comment: I've switched to FlashStopper, and have no problems. I have version 60.0.3112.101 of Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this extension in Chrome:
[**Disable HTML5 Autoplay**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-html5-autoplay/efdhoaajjjgckpbkoglidkeendpkolai?hl=en)

Comment: This is no longer maintained, unfortunately.  Autoplaying videos are the new pop-up windows, I really hope one of the browser vendors come up with a way to permanently disable them without requiring downloading and configuring an add-on.